# Is there a way to add test notes automatically to Testflight internal testing with XcodeCloud

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, testflight, xcode-cloud

I created my own Xcode Cloud workflow that distributes app to internal testers on TestFlight but I can't include the TestFlight test notes into the workflow. Do you know of any strategy to achieve my purpose?

In addition, I don't want to use Fastlane, Codemagic, GitHub actions, or any CI tools to create TestFlight distribution process. I just want to use Xcode Cloud.

If you help me to do that, I'd be very happy.

I've tried setting XCODE_CLOUD_BUILD_NOTES parameters to Environment in workflow according to this @denismartins solution in this link below

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/711208

Unfortunately it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I asked Xcode Cloud engineer and they said is not possible now. They suggest filing a feedback request.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i hope they will enable to use this feature in the future